# Verilog Function - Can't figure out my error

Tags: function, compiler-errors, syntax-error, verilog, system-verilog

I try to compile this code in Modelsim and keep getting the error:

```
** Error: (vlog-13069) q3.sv(2): near "Dividerr": 
syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting ';' or '('.
```

The error is referencing line 2 of my code. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone enlighten me or highlight what I'm missing here? I want to compile this module and be able to write a test bench for it and simulate eventually, but this error is stumping me. I'm used to verilog, but not systemverilog, I have a feeling it's an easy fix.

Here's the code:

```
module integerDiv#(parameter width=16)();
    function Divider Divide;
        input [width-1:0] A, B;
        reg signed [width-1:0] D;
        reg [width-1:0] Result, Remainder;
        integer i;
        divider.Result_ = {width{1'b0}};
        for (i=width-1; i>=0; i=i-1) begin
            Result = (divider.Result_ << 1 ) + A[i];
            Remainder = divider.Result_<<1;
            Remainder = {Remainder[width-1:1], A[i]};
            D = Remainder - B;
            if ( D < 0 ) begin
                divider.D_[i] = 1'b0;
                divider.Result_ = Result;
            end else begin
                divider.D_[i] = 1'b1; 
                divider.Result_ = D;
            end
        end
    endfunction
endmodule
```

Comment: If you are using verilog, then the function declaration is wrong. Verilog uses a function as an operand in an expression; the value of that operand is the value returned by the function. Use something like `function divider`. Moreover there is no sign about what is the type of `divider`.

Comment: the message says `Dividerr` with double 'rr' at the end. There is no such word in the fragment you provided. Where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven’t defined the return type, or maybe you need to import the definition from a `package`. Also you are mixing up the type name with the function name inside the body of the function.

Answer (score 0):

As Serge said, at a minimum, it seems you are you referencing a file/module with a typo (two "rr"s).  Also, remember, Systemverilog/verilog is case-sensitive  Divider/=divider